# Arity exception deref'ing promise

Tags: clojure, promise, dereference

I'm using the http-kit library to make some webcalls and it returns a promise for each. 
When I try to deref any of the promises in the vector I get the following error

*ArityException Wrong number of args (1) passed to: core/eval5473/fn--5474  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.ja
va:429)*

Simplest way to reproduce in a repl without http-kit is as follows

Create collection

```
(def x [ [1 (promise)] [2 (promise)] [3 (promise)]])
```

Simple Test

```
(map first x)
;user=>  (1 2 3)
```

My Test

```
(map #(vector % @%2) x)
;user=> ArityException Wrong number of args (1) passed to: user/eval109/fn--110  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java
:429)
```

### Update

I should probably delete this question. The problem had nothing to do with promises as Valentin noted below.
I was typing %2 and thinking second argument. When what i needed was @(second %). i.e second entry in first and only argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that is the second argument of `map` must accept only 1 argument in this case (which is meant to be an element of the seq that is being walked through).

You seem to be mistaking passing 2 arguments to a function and passing 1 argument that is a vector of 2 elements.

What you want to write is

```
(map (fn [[a b]] (vector a @b)) x)
```

...whereas what you're currently writing is equivalent to:

```
(map (fn [a b] (vector a @b)) x)
```

So this is not a problem about promises in fact.

Comment: small nitpick: the first argument to map should take N-1 arguments, where N is the number of arguments to map. `(map assoc (repeat {}) [:a :b :c :d :e :f] (range 6))`